# take default value instead of setting up a try catch block

Tags: c#

I have to query some data which might be null and throw an exception when accessing them. Let's say I have to query a field of integers

```
int[] numbers = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int targetNumber = numbers[10];
```

I would have to wrap `int targetNumber = numbers[10];` into a try catch block because the index would throw an out of bounds exception.

```
int targetNumber;

try
{
    targetNumber = numbers[10];
}
catch (Exception)
{
    targetNumber = 7; // default value for index 10
}
```

When loading multiple fields this would be very inefficient. I am looking for a way to use something like this

```
int targetNumber = numbers[10] || 7;
```

When the exception was thrown the application will not crash and takes the default value. With this approach I could avoid multiple try catch blocks.

An array of integers was just an example. I'm thinking of complex collections with complex objects. So external libraries could give me access to a collection of type `ICollection` and I can access these collections with a string (key). If the key does not exist, an exception is thrown.

So when accessing these ones with

```
string value = collection["myKey"]
```

I want to extend it to

```
string value = collection["myKey"] || "MyDefaultValueToTakeIfSomethingFailed";
```

Comment: The `collection` could be a `Dictionary<T>`, or you are dealing only with `List<T>` and arrays?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

About the closest I can think of to what you want is to use an inline if to test the length of the array to ensure it contains an element at index 10 (11th item)

```
int targetNumber = numbers.Length > 10 ? numbers[10] : 7;
```

It's not that theres a null reference, it's that your array isn't long enough to supply index 10 (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException)

The basic rule is "if numbers array length is greater than X retrieve element at X" - if there are 11 items or more, then retrieving [10] will work out

If you're using something nullable, then you can also use the ?? operator to provide a default

```
string targetString = (strings.Length > 10 ? strings[10] : null)  ?? "defaultstring";
```

You can't quite get away from the two different exceptions; ArrayIndexOutOfBounds, and NullReferenceexception - the length test prevents the out-of-bounds, and then you can prevent nulls (which may be that element 10 is null or array isn't long enough) with ??

Comment: sorry, I edited my question. Having integer arrays was just an example

Comment: I believe the advice is still valid; the basic premise of "i'm trying to retrieve the 10th element from an array that only contains 5 elements" still seems on point after your edit but i added some more info anyway

Comment: Upvoted because I needed to delete my question which you answered yesterday. I think it's fine for me to upvote this instead because this is a good answer. (I deleted that question because it was getting downvotes. I miss the old StackOverflow...) Thanks for that answer (to press tab after `byte[] b = new` to get `byte`).

Answer (score 6):

You can use LINQ:

```
int targetNumber = numbers.Cast<int?>().ElementAtOrDefault(10) ?? 7;
```

The `Cast` will make the elements you pick from nullable, which will cause `ElementAtOrDefault` to return `null` in case you don't hit an entry. Finally the null coalescing operator `??` will make the expression your default value in case it was `null`.

If your array contains reference types or nullable value types, you can go without the cast:

```
string targetString = strings.ElementAtOrDefault(10) ?? "default";
```

In this case you can expect `ElementAtOrDefault` to check for `IList<T>` and `ICollection<T>` in the base object, so it will not iterate the entire array here, but evaluate its length and pick the value directly from its index.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a tookit with extension methods, with identical signatures, applicable to various data types. The compiler will select the proper one at compile time, so at run time the performance would be optimal.

```
public static class GetValueExtensions
{
    public static T GetValue<T>(this T[] source, int key, T defaultValue) // Array
    {
        if (key >= 0 && key < source.Length) return source[key];
        return defaultValue;
    }

    public static T GetValue<T>(this IList<T> source, int key, T defaultValue) // List
    {
        if (key >= 0 && key < source.Count) return source[key];
        return defaultValue;
    }

    public static TValue GetValue<TKey, TValue>( // Dictionary
        this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> source, TKey key, TValue defaultValue)
    {
        if (source.TryGetValue(key, out TValue value)) return value;
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
var s = new string[] { "Foo", "Bar" }.GetValue(5, "Empty"); // Returns "Empty"
var c = new List<char> { 'a', 'b', 'c' }.GetValue(2, '_'); // Returns 'c'
var b = new Dictionary<int, bool>() { { 1, false }, { 2, true } }
    .GetValue(13, true); // Returns true
```

If you want to avoid repeating the default value again and again, you can go functional:

```
public static Func<int, T> GetGetter<T>(this T[] source, T defaultValue)
{
    return (key) =>
    {
        if (key >= 0 && key < source.Length) return source[key];
        return defaultValue;
    };
}
```

Usage example:

```
var getFooBar = new string[] { "Foo", "Bar" }.GetGetter("Empty");
var x = getFooBar(0); // Returns "Foo"
var y = getFooBar(5); // Returns "Empty"
```